# How to calculate the volume obtained by rotating the following around the x axis?

Tags: calculus, integration

The original problem is:

"Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating about the x axis the region enclosed by the curves $y = \frac{9}{x^2 + 9},y=0,x=0,\,$and $x = 3$"

I set up the following integral $$81\pi\int_0^3\frac{1}{(x^2 + 9)^2}dx$$ using the cylinder method (I believe it's called like that) and when I calculated it using a computer I obtained the correct answer but I have been having difficulties in solving it manually.  I tried the shell method as well and I didn't see it any easier to solve but I may be wrong of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to find 
$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+9)^2}.$$
Let $x=3u$. Apart from a constant factor, we end up with
$$\int\frac{du}{(u^2+1)^2}.$$

Let $u=\tan t$ (we could have gone more directly, by letting $x=3\tan t$).  Then $du=\sec^2 t\,dt$, and we end up with
$$\int \frac{\sec^2 t}{\sec^4 t}\,dt.$$
This is the familiar integral
$$\int \cos^2 t\,dt.$$
A common approach to this is to use the fact that $\cos 2t=2\cos^2 t-1$.

e can save time if we make the substitutions on the **definite** integral, that is, substitute for the endpoints.

**Another way:** Consider $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{x^2+9}$. Attack this by integration by parts, letting $du=dx$ and $v=\frac{1}{9+x^2}$. Then we can take $u=x$. Also, $dv=\frac{-2x\,dx}{(x^2+9)^2}$. Thus
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+9}=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+\int\frac{2x^2\,dx}{(x^2+9)^2}.$$
But $2x^2=2x^2+18-18$. Thus
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+9}=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+2\int\frac{dx}{x^2+9}-18\int\frac{dx}{(9+x^2)^2}.$$
We will be finished if we can find $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{x^2+9}$. The substitution $x=3w$ turns this into a familiar integral.

**Remark:** In the second approach, we obtained a *reduction formula*. A very similar trick expresses $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+9)^{n+1}}$ in terms of 
$\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+9)^{n}}$

Comment: Do you suggest the students memorize a suitable formula for the integral the OP faced above? Or you always prefer to apply methods to find the best approach? Thanks. +

Comment: I have always suggested to students that they remember *approaches*. Many prefer to try to memorize formulas. In the short run such memorization is often ineffective. In the long run it is disastrous.

Answer (score 2):

Although the integral you've got can be evaluated by some technical method, as @Andre noted completely; you can use The cylinder method instead. According to this method we consider the following integral: $$V=2\pi\int_{y=a}^{y=b}x|f(x)|dx$$ So we have here: $$\int_0^118\pi x\frac{1}{x^2+9}dx$$.
[image]

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Thanks for your support.